# Change button backgoundColor

Tags: ios, xcode, button, background-color

I'm trying to change a button color then I tap on it but it's not working because to do so I have to detect which color the button currently has to change to the next color.

```
if (sender.backgroundColor == [UIColor clearColor]) {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
} else if (sender.backgroundColor == [UIColor grayColor]) {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
} else if (sender.backgroundColor == [UIColor blueColor]) {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
} else {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.
Does anyone know how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *buttonTapped = sender;

if (buttonTapped.backgroundColor == [UIColor clearColor]) {
  [buttonTapped setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor];
} else if (buttonTapped.backgroundColor == [UIColor grayColor) {
  [buttonTapped setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor];
} else if (buttonTapped.backgroundColor == [UIColor blueColor) {
  [buttonTapped setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor];
} else {
  [buttonTapped setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Try this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you are using "==" to compare colors, which are objects - not primitives. What you want to do is compare colors like this:

```
if ([buttonTapped.backgroundColor isEqual: [UIColor clearColor]]) {
  [buttonTapped setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor];
}
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
if ([btn.backgroundColor isEqual:someOtherColor]) {
  [buttonTapped setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks